# Getting rid of splits (like a railroad switch) in my Git repo

Tags: git

I've made a mistake and now my tree looks like this, instead of just one line. It has a split. Is there anything I can do to get rid of this split? I've tried rebasing from the bottom, but I might've done it wrong, or it doesn't solve it. Even squashing two commits kept the split.

What I have:

```
* hash message
* hash message
|\
| * hash (tag b) message
* | hash message
* | hash message
|/
* hash (tag a) message
* hash message
```

What I want:

```
* hash message
* hash message
* hash (tag b) message
* hash message
* hash message
* hash (tag a) message
* hash message
```

Comment: Why, though? Is it causing problems? What are they?

Comment: It has so many splits like that and useless messages it's made the log incomprehensible.

Comment: What happened when you tried rebasing "from the bottom"? That *should* work. Though, if any of the merges (what you're calling "splits") had conflicts to resolve at the time they were created, you'll get prompted to redo those conflicts during the rebase.